Impossible to create the line item creative association between an adExchange creative and an Adexchange line item on Google ad manager using the API
I've been creating an AdExchange Line Item and an Ad Exchange creative on Google Ad Manager using the API.
Now I can't create the line item creative association between the two objects.
Creative is as follows :
Creative = {
    'advertiserId': [ADVERTISER_ID],
    'id': [CREATIVE_ID],
    'name': 'My Ad Exchange creative',
    'size': {
        'width': 1,
        'height': 1,
        'isAspectRatio': False
    },
    'previewUrl': '[PREVIEW_URL]',
    'policyLabels': [],
    'appliedLabels': [],
    'lastModifiedDateTime': {[CREATION_TIME]},
    'customFieldValues': [],
    'thirdPartyDataDeclaration': None,
    'codeSnippet': "[CODE_SNIPPET]",
    'isNativeEligible': False,
    'isInterstitial': False,
    'isAllowsAllRequestedSizes': False
}

And has been created using following instructions :
Creative = {
            'advertiserId': [ADVERTISER_ID],
            'xsi_type': 'AdExchangeCreative',
            'name': 'My Ad Exchange creative',
            'size': {
                'width': 1,
                'height': 1,
                'isAspectRatio': False
            }
            ,'codeSnippet': "[CODE_SNIPPET]"
        }
service("CreativeService").createCreatives([Creative])

Line item is of course a lot bigger object but let me give some details :
line = {
    [...]
    'id': [LINE_ID],
    'lineItemType': 'AD_EXCHANGE',
    'priority': 12,
    'creativePlaceholders': [
        {
            'size': {
                'width': 1,
                'height': 1,
                'isAspectRatio': False
            },
            'creativeTemplateId': None,
            'companions': [],
            'appliedLabels': [],
            'effectiveAppliedLabels': [],
            'expectedCreativeCount': 1,
            'creativeSizeType': 'IGNORED',
            'targetingName': None,
            'isAmpOnly': False
        }
    ],
}

The important thing here is to note that line item is an AdExchange one and has a creative placeholder containing the size of the previously created creative.
I've been trying different setups to link the two like eg :
association = {'creativeId': [CREATIVE_ID],'lineItemId': [LINE_ID]}

or :
association = {'creativeId': [CREATIVE_ID],'lineItemId': [LINE_ID], 'sizes':[]}

or :
association = {'creativeId': [CREATIVE_ID],'lineItemId': [LINE_ID],
    sizes :[ {'width': 1,'height': 1,'isAspectRatio': False}
}

But whatever the setup among these used into the createLineItemCreativeAssociations function, I always get the same error message :
googleads.errors.GoogleAdsServerFault: [RequiredSizeError.NOT_ALLOWED @ [0].size; trigger:'1x1-null']

Has anyone bumped into that issue before, and maybe figured out a solution ?
